# Como não transcrever dados no visual studios. Em C

Tags: c

Preciso fazer um programa de uma lanchonete que o usuário precise digitar o item que deseja e quantidade, e no final do programa tudo o que ele comprou é mostrado, suas quantidades e o valor total da compra.

Preciso fazer um código especifico que o usuário digita ***(3,3,2)*** no programa que seriam os itens selecionados e ***(2,0,7)*** que seriam a quantidade de cada um desses itens, mas um dos itens se repete. **o item de n° 3** pórem na quantidade **0** e no final do programa os dados são substituídos já que se escolheu o mesmo item novamente mas na quantidade 0. Como posso evitar esse problema para que no final o item fique com a quantidade certa que seria **2** e não **0**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TOTAL_PRODUTOS 7

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    float  total[TOTAL_PRODUTOS], preco_final= 0;
    int cont, op, qtd[TOTAL_PRODUTOS];
    char produtos[TOTAL_PRODUTOS] [30];
    
    strcpy_s(produtos[0], "Cachorro-quente");
    strcpy_s(produtos[1], "X-Salada");
    strcpy_s(produtos[2], "X-Bacon");
    strcpy_s(produtos[3], "Misto");
    strcpy_s(produtos[4], "Salada");
    strcpy_s(produtos[5], "Água");
    strcpy_s(produtos[6], "Refrigerante");


        printf("Lanchonete LTD\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Item | Produto         | Código | Preço unitário |\n");
    printf("1    | Cachorro Quente | 100    | 5,00           |\n");
    printf("2    | X-Salada        | 101    | 8,79           |\n");
    printf("3    | X-Bacon         | 102    | 9,99           |\n");
    printf("4    | Misto           | 103    | 6,89           |\n");
    printf("5    | Salada          | 104    | 4,80           |\n");
    printf("6    | Água            | 105    | 3,49           |\n");
    printf("7    | Refrigerante    | 106    | 4,99           |\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Digite o número do item desejado:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &op);

    
    
    
    
    while ((op <= 7) && (op > 0))
    {
    
        switch (op)
        {
            while ( qtd >0 )
        case 1: // Cachorro-quente

            printf("Você escolheu o item:\n");
            puts(produtos[0]);
            printf("Digite a quantidade desse item:\n");
            scanf_s("%i", &qtd [0]);
            total[0] = qtd[0] * 5.00;
                break;
        case 2: // X - salada
            printf("Você escolheu o item:\n");
            puts(produtos[1]);
            printf("Digite a quantidade desse item:\n");
            scanf_s("%i", &qtd[1]);
            total[1] = qtd[1] * 8.79;
            break;
        case 3: // X -bacon 
            printf("Você escolheu o item:\n");
            puts(produtos[2]);
            printf("Digite a quantidade desse item:\n");
            scanf_s("%i", &qtd[2]);
            total[2] = qtd[2] * 9.99;
            break;
        case 4: // Misto
            printf("Você escolheu o item:\n");
            puts(produtos[3]);
            printf("Digite a quantidade desse item:\n");
            scanf_s("%i", &qtd[3]);
            total[3] = qtd[3] * 6.89;
            break;
        case 5: // Salada
            printf("Você escolheu o item:\n");
            puts(produtos[4]);
            printf("Digite a quantidade desse item:\n");
            scanf_s("%i", &qtd[4]);
            total[4] = qtd[4] * 4.80;
            break;
        case 6: // Água 
            printf("Você escolheu o item:\n");
            puts(produtos[5]);
            printf("Digite a quantidade desse item:\n");
            scanf_s("%i", &qtd[5]);
            total[5] = qtd[5] * 3.49;
            break;
        case 7: // refrigerante
            printf("Você escolheu o item:\n");
            puts(produtos[6]);
            printf("Digite a quantidade desse item:\n");
            scanf_s("%i", &qtd[6]);
            total[6] = qtd[6] * 4.99;
            break;
            

        }


        
        
        printf("Digite o número do item desejado:\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &op);
            
    }
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < TOTAL_PRODUTOS;i++)
    {
        if (qtd[i] >= 0)
        {
            puts(produtos[i]);
            printf("Quantidade do item: %i || Total a pagar do item: %.2f\n",qtd[i], total [i]);
            preco_final += total[i];
        }

    }

    printf("Total do pedido:%.3f", preco_final);



    system; "pause";
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse  `while ( qtd >0 )` dentro de um `switch` mas fora de um `case` não existe, é muito errado. Um outro problema é que vc está deixando muito confuso pra que serve a variável de quantidade, ela é um contador de compras de um produto ou faz parte do caixa? Seria melhor algo como:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define TOTAL_PRODUTOS 7

int menu_principal()
{
    int op = -1;
    while(op < 0 || op > 7)
    {
        printf("Lanchonete LTD\n");
        printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Item | Produto         | Código | Preço unitário |\n");
        printf("1    | Cachorro Quente | 100    | 5,00           |\n");
        printf("2    | X-Salada        | 101    | 8,79           |\n");
        printf("3    | X-Bacon         | 102    | 9,99           |\n");
        printf("4    | Misto           | 103    | 6,89           |\n");
        printf("5    | Salada          | 104    | 4,80           |\n");
        printf("6    | Água            | 105    | 3,49           |\n");
        printf("7    | Refrigerante    | 106    | 4,99           |\n");
        printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Digite o número do item desejado:\n");
        scanf("%d", &op);
    }
    return op;
}

bool sub_menu(int opcao, int qtd[TOTAL_PRODUTOS], char produtos[TOTAL_PRODUTOS][30])
{
    if(opcao < 1)
        return false;

    int id_produto = opcao-1;
    int qtd_produto = 0;
    printf("Você escolheu o item:\n");
    puts(produtos[id_produto]);
    printf("Digite a quantidade desse item:\n");
    scanf("%i", &qtd_produto);
    qtd[id_produto] = qtd[id_produto] + qtd_produto;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    float preco_final = 0;
    float precos[TOTAL_PRODUTOS] = {
        5.0, 8.79, 9.99, 6.89, 4.8, 3.49, 4.99
    };

    int qtd[TOTAL_PRODUTOS];
    for(int i=0; i<TOTAL_PRODUTOS; i++)
        qtd[i] = 0;

    char produtos[TOTAL_PRODUTOS][30] = {
        "Cachorro-quente",
        "X-Salada",
        "X-Bacon",
        "Misto",
        "Salada",
        "Água",
        "Refrigerante"
    };

    while(sub_menu(menu_principal(), qtd, produtos));

    for(int i=0; i<TOTAL_PRODUTOS; i++)
    {
        if (qtd[i] > 0)
        {
            puts(produtos[i]);
            printf("Quantidade do item: %i || Total a pagar do item: %.2f\n",
                    qtd[i], qtd[i]*precos[i]);
            preco_final += qtd[i]*precos[i];
        }
    }

    printf("Total do pedido:%.3f", preco_final);

    return 0;
}
```